# JIRA: Syntax error: "(" unexpected when installing on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, java

Trying to install JIRA on my raspberry pi2 and I keep getting the following error.

```
Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
/usr/local/jira/atlassian-jira.bin.28540.dir/jre/bin/java: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

After some time researching the error it seems that it could be related to the version of JAVA installed on my Raspbian distro but I can't find any directions or figure out what version/build of JAVA it needs. Can I only install ARM based versions and does it matter for JIRA to run?

Is it possible to install JIRA on a raspberry pi? I know it's not the most powerful hardware but the usage is 1-3 users 1-10 projects so I figured it should be enough to handle that.

Comment: Where did you get this from?   If that has its own `jre/bin` (which it appears to), that stuff has to have been compiled for the pi.   The distro java does not look to be in use here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with JIRA or Java, but with the installer script. My best guess is you are trying to install JIRA using one of the full platform installers.
My advice is to install it using a manual process and just deploying the JIRA war into a Tomcat container.

UPDATE: this is what Atlassian suggests: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Installing+JIRA+WAR

Comment: Is there a tutorial you could point me to, have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Isn't the link I provided enough? I never tried to install JIRA on a RPi myself, so I can't directly help.